# Foreach over where class CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to setup a query that targets the database from a foreach. I'm recieving an array as data and want to loop over it. I only want to recieve the items that are correct on all, so id field one needs to be the key and field 2 needs to be the defined value.

```php
$array = array(1 => false, 2 => false, 3 => true);
```

Start of the query:

```php
$query = $this->find()->innerJoinWith('Table');
```

my foreach():

```php
foreach ($array as $key => $checkpoint) {
    query = $query->where([
       'AND' => [
          'Table.field1' => $key, 
          'Table.field2' => $checkpoint
       ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my IDE:

> Adds a condition or set of conditions to be used in the WHERE clause
> for this query. Conditions can be expressed as an array of fields as
> keys with comparison operators in it, the values for the array will be
> used for comparing the field to such literal. Finally, conditions can
> be expressed as a single string or an array of strings. When using
> arrays, each entry will be joined to the rest of the conditions using
> an AND operator. Consecutive calls to this function will also join the
> new conditions specified using the AND operator. Additionally, values
> can be expressed using expression objects which can include other
> query objects. Any conditions created with this methods can be used
> with any SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE type of queries. Conditions using
> operators:

```php
$query->where([
    'posted >='  => new DateTime('3 days ago'),
    'title LIKE' => 'Hello W%',
    'author_id'  => 1,
], ['posted' => 'datetime']);
```

> The previous example produces: WHERE posted >= 2012-01-27 AND title LIKE 'Hello W%' AND author_id = 1

So in your case, I think it should be:

```php
foreach ($array as $key => $checkpoint) {
    $query->where([
          'Table.field1' => $key, 
          'Table.field2' => $checkpoint
    ]);
}
```

Note: I didn't take the join statement in consideration.